# how can I disable the layout in zend ver 1.11

Tags: zend-framework

I am working on zend framework. 
I am adding a popup in detail page but it shows the layout. I don't want layout to be shown.
I have tried by using disable layout. but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout()
```

This is a simplest way you can use almost anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
```

i do this to disable layout and always working.
if not, post your code here.

*Sorry for my bad English!*